# Manage state data in Microsoft Azure Bot SDK V4 using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

Can we have Manage state data in SDK V4 using Nodejs? I currently have used in SDK V3 using the link below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information in the v3 docs can also be found in the v4 docs. The docs are just structured differently.

Check out this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) which provides an overview on "Managing State". There is also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) which discusses how to "Save user and conversation data" as well as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) that goes over "Writing directly to storage".

Hope of help!